# Version of SSIS in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have installed sql server 2012, visual studio on 2 VMs (running windows server 2012) from the same binaries

SSIS Packages are version 6 on one server and version 7 in another.

As you see in picture below SSIS is version 12 in one server and 11 in another

[image: version OF SSIS from within VS]

I cannot find out what makes version different.

I looked to windows updates and noticed some additional sql server patches and .NET framework in server with version 12

I removed them. Now windows updates shows the same updates and fixes on both machines but SSIS is still different

I'm looking for a solution to downgrade 12 to 11 cause I cannot deploy packages from one server to another and packages with v7 don't run in sql server. I get error message telling that SSIS cannot run version 7.

Please help! since the development is stopped due to this problem

Comment: 11 is SQL Server 2012 and 12 is SQL Server 2014.

Comment: there's no 2014. same binaries 2012 were used to install both servers.

Comment: But the SSIS designer that has been installed correlates to the two SQL Server products. First is run under VS 2010/2012 while the later is VS 2013

Comment: same binaries were used for install. VS 2012 was used. 
there's no VS 2013.
I don't have it.
Unless it was updated automatically and cannot find how